# Python script in jupyter runs forever

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Python scripts, even simple ones run in `jupyter` forever. I have to stop anaconda and re launch notebook in order to run scripts again. What may be some reasons?

`print ("hello")`

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the ol' turn it on and off again/uninstall and reinstall?

Comment: But that can't be a reason. We can't just all the time reinstall stuff

Comment: It's not the answer I'd want either, but it's where I'd look to start. Assuming you're using Anaconda, if you run ipython/python from the command line, do commands work in there, or do they also hang?

Comment: Have you installed `nb_conda_kernels` ?

Comment: If you can, stop depending on Anaconda Distributions. It has so many libraries and software that you probably won't need. Do the manual installation.

This should help :

Just go to the website https://www.python.org/downloads/ download and install python.

And if you want Jupyter or Spyder you can open command prompt and simply run

`pip install jupyter` and
`pip install spyder`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and your question answered it for me: "I have to stop anaconda." Thank you.

One can do so by ensuring that conda is deactivated by running:

```
conda deactivate
```

Ensure that it does not have "(base)" before in the terminal or anything else in parentheses.

NOT [image: (base) MacBook-Pro-4:~]

NOT [image: (/Users/jw1/opt/anaconda3) MacBook-Pro-4:~]

YES [image]

So in this case, I had to run 'conda deactivate' twice.